# Twilio StatusCallback POST retrial logic?

Tags: twilio

I've looked around but haven't been able to find a definite answer.

What happens if Twilio performs the POST to the StatusCallback url but the service is unavailable or something else fails? (i.e. A HTTP status other than 200 is returned)

Will Twilio retry the request if it didn't work the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

So the short answer is "no", as we will make the assumption your server is up and that the request can be made.

I have seen alternatives to this being done in two ways.

The first one is to make a request to a middleware server that is always up (cloud server for example), and caches the request. That way, you have control whether to retry the request to your server or not. You could then queue those requests for example, and have the queue controlling whether a request or successful or needs to be retried.

A much more robust way to do that however would be by using [Monitor](https://www.twilio.com/monitor). Monitor gives you operational monitoring of Twilio accounts and apps, which also includes whether a certain request was successful or not.

You can use it by checking all the StatusCallback requests, and checking which ones failed. In case you find one that failed, you can then retry that request yourself.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I think a separate service is a little overkill for my needs right now, but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Great! Monitor should be helpful for that. Give me a shout if you come up with any new questions